# Fourier Lapalacian over periodic end

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, gauge-theory

This  is a technical question on Taubes' paper: Gauge theory over periodic end. on Page 378.

Recall that:

Let $Y$ be a closed manifold, with $b_1=1$, and $\tilde Y$ be the $\mathbb Z$-covering of $Y$.

Denote    $T$ the deck transformation over $\tilde Y$, $W_k$ the $k$-th. copy of the fundamental  component of  $\tilde Y$.

Let $\tilde E_j$ be the periodic vector bundle over $\tilde Y$, for $\psi\in \Gamma_c(\tilde E_j)$, the Fourier Lapalacian transformation is,
$$\hat \psi_z=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}z^nT^n\psi, ~z\in\mathbb C.$$

Similarly, we have the inverse Fourier Lapalacian transformation.

Suppose $\beta_q(x)=1,x\in W_l$ with $|l|<q$ and $\beta_q(x)=0, x\in W_l$ with $|l|>q+1$.

Let $\psi_q=\beta_q\psi_z/q^{1/p}$, here $\psi_z$ is the inverse Fourier Lapalacian transformation of  $\hat \psi_z$.

**Q**: If we have that $\|\psi_q-b-\partial\eta_q\|_{L^p(\tilde E_j)}\to0$ as $q\to\infty$, How to say

$$\|\hat\psi_z-q^{1/p-1}\partial_Y\hat\eta_{q,z}\|\to0,~q\to\infty.$$

I donot follow how to let the Fourier Laplacian $\hat b_z$ go to zero?